# How to adjust left-click behavior in JUnit tests in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just recently switched from Eclipse to Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.3.

Within junit tests, it offers a little green circle with subscript arrow to run individual tests. What's annoying me is that when I left-click or right-click, it pops a context menu to run or debug or run-with-coverage. Is there a way to configure Intellij so that if I left-click, it will immediately run the test, and if I right-click, it will open the context menu?

[image: left&rightclick context-menu]

(as an aside, should this question be on SuperUser instead of SO?)

Comment: Well, as it shows, Ctrl+Shift+F10 if you just want to run it

Comment: @jingx That's cool, but I'd still like a way to visually click on the green button to run the test immediately rather than have to move my cursor into whatever test I want to run before hitting a key combo

Comment: You may create the feature request (usability problem) issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've made an issue on the JetBrains tracker regarding this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223298